# Running a c program causes 2 consoles to open

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm new to C. When I run even a simple tutorial program that prints something to the console, it opens up 2 consoles.

For example, running this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    int c = a + b;
    printf("%d", a);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

gives me this:
[image]

Comment: How did you create your project? This won't happen if you start with the default console app template.

Comment: My steps were File->New Project->Win32 Console Application (with Empty Project selected). I did this based on a tutorial I was following

Comment: Can't reproduce here

Comment: In the version of Visual Studio I'm using (Visual Studio Express 2013), when you select Win32 Console Application, it gives you configuration options you can choose (Precompiled header,DLL, etc.)

Comment: Yup. And in there there is Empty project. Check that. Add a new item, named `Source.c` as per your screenshot. Add the code. I do that, cannot repro.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Right. I don't believe this is a Visual Studio issue, as this happened as well when I tried using Eclipse

Comment: If you are using Avast as a virus detector, turn off DeepScan or whatever it is called.